# Silencing clang-tidy

Tags: qt, cmake, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

I have a build which uses clang-tidy through cmake:

```
set_target_properties(project
    PROPERTIES
    ...
    CXX_CLANG_TIDY
        "/usr/bin/clang-tidy"
        "-checks=modernize-*,readability-*,performance-*"
        "-fix"
)
```

While building it I am getting a possible memory leak inside the Qt libraries:

```
/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:242:16: warning: Potential memory leak [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]
        return connectImpl(sender, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&signal),
               ^
.../a.cpp:27:5: note: Taking false branch
    if (not inputQFile.makeAbsolute()) {
    ^
.../a.cpp:33:5: note: Calling 'QObject::connect'
    connect(this, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
    ^
/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:238:13: note: Left side of '||' is false
        if (type == Qt::QueuedConnection || type == Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection)
            ^
/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:238:9: note: Taking false branch
        if (type == Qt::QueuedConnection || type == Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection)
        ^
/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:242:16: note: Potential memory leak
        return connectImpl(sender, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&signal),
               ^
```

How can I silence this?

What I already tried:

1. Add a `// NOLINT` to the end of a.cpp:33 -> no effect
2. Add a `// NOLINT` to the end of qobject.h:242 -> no effect
3. Wrap qobject.h:242 in a `#ifndef __clang_analyzer__` -> no effect
4. Wrap all of qobject.h in a `#ifndef __clang_analyzer__` -> no effect
5. Add `// NOLINT` to all lines of connectImpl -> clang-tidy crashes

@Tarod:
Here is what I currently have:

```
#ifndef __clang_analyzer__
        return connectImpl(sender, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&signal),
                           receiver, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&slot),
                           new QtPrivate::QSlotObject<Func2, typename QtPrivate::List_Left<typename SignalType::Arguments, SlotType::ArgumentCount>::Value, // NOLINT
                                           typename SignalType::ReturnType>(slot),
                            type, types, &SignalType::Object::staticMetaObject); // NOLINT
#endif //__clang_analyzer__
```

Comment: `#ifndef __clang_analyzer__` should work. Are you putting `#endif` at the end of `qobject.h` file?

Comment: @Tarod I updated the question

Comment: Same issue if you put `#ifndef __clang_analyzer__` at the beginning of the `qobject.h` file?

Comment: @Tarod added the whole file in the #ifndef and still prints the error...

Comment: Mmm... Could you try with `ifdef` instead of `ifndef`? Just to see the difference in the analysis.

Comment: I assume this question is unrelated to both [qt] and [cmake]. It is a pure clang-tidy question, right?

Answer (score 3):

I think you must comment all of your 5 lines of connectImpl() or similar since `// NOLINT` affects a single code line, only.<sup>[(1)](https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/31)</sup>

Comment: If I do that clang-tidy crashes... Error running '/usr/bin/clang-tidy'

Comment: muahaha, this looks like a well-tested tool... ;) Do you use their latest version?

Comment: Yup I did use the latest version. 3.9.1

Answer (score 1):

If you used clang-tidy in the QtCreator see

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20744

QtCreator uses the extra-tools and that lib doesnt support //NOLINT etc yet.